# Python format Integer into fixed length strings

Tags: python

I want to generate a string based on an `int` along with zeros. And the length should always be of `5` not more then that nor less.

```
For example:

Consider a Integer: 1
Formatted String : 00001

Consider a Integer: 12
Formatted String : 00012

Consider a Integer: 110
Formatted String : 00110

Consider a Integer: 1111
Formatted String : 01111

Consider a Integer: 11111
Formatted String : 11111
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) or the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method to format integers with zero-padding:

```
print format(integervalue, '05d')
print 'Formatted String : {0:05d}'.format(integervalue)
```

See the [*Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language); the leading `0` in the format signifies 0-padding, the `5` is the minimal field width; any number shorter than that is padded to the full width.

Demo:

```
>>> format(110, '05d')
'00110'
>>> 'Formatted String : {0:05d}'.format(12)
'Formatted String : 00012'
```

Comment: I found this useful too:
`print "position: {0:5d}, fix id: {1} padded wait in seconds: {2:03d}".format(12, 453585, 89)"`
I mean, you can avoid padding with 0 (as in position)

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna: sure, but the question specifically asked for padding with zeros. :-)

Comment: You can also use f-strings (Python >=3.6): 
f'{integervalue:05d}'

Comment: "the length should always be of 5 __not more__ then [sic] that nor less.": `format(123456, '05d')` → `'123456'`